# Change segue animation without using storyboards?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, segue

I am currently doing everything programmatically in my Swift project. I don't use the Mainstoryboard in any way shape or form. I have my rootViewController set in my AppDelegate and the way I perform segues / "show" controllers is by using either:

```
let homeController = RegisterController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(homeController, animated: true)
```

OR

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeController)
        present(navigationController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Using this, only allows me to have animation set to true or false, without any options to select what animation I would like. Using the presentViewController function makes the view go up from the bottom of the screen. The pushViewController function slides the controller in from the left. How do I change the animation used when using these functions? Any help will be apprecited. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in to change the animations of storyboard segues.

You can animate the segues by using `UIView.animateWithDuration` and control the transition.

[In this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/custom-segue-animations/), you can find a detailed explanation.